# How to get from list with indication in numbers to data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

How to I convert the following list to a data frame? I have tried using data.frame but I get a data frame with 1 object and all the information in the rows of that object.

Is there a way to capture the numbers so I get the correct data per row (two rows, one per page) and with the correct labels (second list below)?

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "https://page1"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4534

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3453

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 2343

[[1]][[5]]
[1] 0.2806075

[[1]][[6]]
[1] 0.4386998


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "https://page2"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 9166

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 6294

[[2]][[4]]
[1] 698

[[2]][[5]]
[1] 0.1489971

[[2]][[6]]
[1] 0.1963775

list number two:

$columns
$columns[[1]]
[1] "event_url"

$columns[[2]]
[1] "page_views"

$columns[[3]]
[1] "unique_page_views"

$columns[[4]]
[1] "entries"

$columns[[5]]
[1] "bounce_rate_events"

$columns[[6]]
[1] "exit_rate"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(list1, function(x) setNames(as.data.frame(x), unlist(list2))))
#>       event_url page_views unique_page_views entries bounce_rate_events exit_rate
#> 1 https://page1       4534              3453    2343          0.2806075 0.4386998
#> 2 https://page2       9166              6294     698          0.1489971 0.1963775
```

---

**Data**

```r
list1 <- list(
  list("https://page1", 4534, 3453, 2343, 0.2806075, 0.4386998),
  list("https://page2", 9166, 6294, 698, 0.1489971, 0.1963775))

list2 <- list(columns = list("event_url", "page_views",
                             "unique_page_views", "entries",
                             "bounce_rate_events", "exit_rate"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(list1, bind_cols) %>% 
            set_names(unlist(list2))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  event_url     page_views unique_page_views entries bounce_rate_events exit_rate
#  <chr>              <dbl>             <dbl>   <dbl>              <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 https://page1       4534              3453    2343              0.281     0.439
#2 https://page2       9166              6294     698              0.149     0.196
```